# What's the best way to feed MySQL table data to ElasticSearch in real-time?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, rds

I need to feed MySQL (deployed with RDS on AWS) table data into ElasticSearch in real-time or near-real-time (maybe several minutes of delay), joining a couple tables in the process.

The first option I have investigated is Flink. But after some research I couldn't find a way to stream table data change because the tables are not append-only.

Then I found that some people are talking about CDC(Change Data Capture), basically streaming MySQL binlog changes to a lambda and parse it then post to ElasticSearch, but this just sounds too complicated and error prone.

Is there any industry tried-and-true ways to sync non-append-only tables to ElasticSearch?

Comment: Probably you should use Logstash to import your data from binlog. Search "sync mysql and elasticsearch" on google and you will see lots of results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Best way to sync data from mysql to elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746052/what-is-the-best-way-to-sync-data-from-mysql-to-elastic-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logstash script to fetch data from mysql to elasticsearch.

Sample Logstash Code

```
    input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "<pathToYourDataBaseDriver>\mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecomdb"
    jdbc_user => <db username>
    jdbc_password => <db password>
    tracking_column¹ => "regdate"
    use_column_value²=>true
    statement => "SELECT * FROM ecomdb.customer where regdate >:sql_last_value;"
    schedule³ => " * * * * * *"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    document_id⁴=> "%{id}"
    document_type => "doc"
    index => "test"
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout{
  codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```